# Identifying and Replacing Capacitor

Tags: diy-3d-printer, electronics, repair, flashforge-creator

So during one of my initial experiments I accidentally blew up one of my capacitors. Everything else works on the board except the motor control with the blown capacitor so I'm going to replace it. Now I know it's an SMD and its capacitance is 47 µF, I'm going to assume that the "H" marks it as a 50 VDC on its voltage rating and it has a diameter of 6.3 mm as measured with my caliper. I can't find anything that read the exact same as what is on the capacitor shown, does that matter or does only the capacitance and voltage rating matter? [assuming my idea of the voltage rating being 50 VDC is correct]

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this question attract more attention when posted on EE.SE?

Comment: What did you do to blow that cap? It seems likely that anything you could do to blow a cap would damage other components also.

Comment: Usually only the capacitance and voltage matter. And it has to actually fit on the circuit board of course.

Comment: I put 33 volts through my board like a dummy and it blew out the capacitor for the x controller and fried the motor control but that's an easy replacement as I have extra motor controllers. Only the x motor controller was affected by this overload. I checked all the other components with my voltmeter and everything else reads normal.

Comment: That capacitor is in parallel with all of the other motor capacitors. I think it is unlikely to be the culprit for that particular motor driver not working. Also, how do you blow up a 50V rated capacitor with 33V?